# Why will thread run faster with thread.Join in Visual Basic .Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have two windows form to test the performance of using threat

I do a looping of 500

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 500
    'Form 1 scenario
    Dim Thread1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf InsertRecord1)
    Thread1.Start(RunningID)
    Dim Thread2 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf InsertRecord1)
    Thread2.Start(RunningID)
    Dim Thread3 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf InsertRecord1)
    Thread3.Start(RunningID)
    Dim Thread4 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf InsertRecord1)
    Thread4.Start(RunningID)
Next
```

Form 2 scenario

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 500
    'Form 2 scenario
    Dim Thread1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf InsertRecord1)
    Thread1.Start(RunningID)
    Dim Thread2 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf InsertRecord1)
    Thread2.Start(RunningID)
    Dim Thread3 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf InsertRecord1)
    Thread3.Start(RunningID)
    Dim Thread4 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf InsertRecord1)
    Thread4.Start(RunningID)
    Thread1.Join()
    Thread2.Join()
    Thread3.Join()
    Thread4.Join()
Next
```

Apparently Scenario 2 is faster than scenario 1. why??

this is the data collected

```
Scenario 1 take (milliseconds): 2578   3188   3078   2984   3250
Scenario 2 take (milliseconds): 1890   1969   1828   1938   1860
```

Comment: Cough.... Scenarios 2 "is faster" when the time it takes to finish work is LONGER? IS that a fail of basic math or just a bad explanation?

Comment: how are you doing your counting of milliseconds?

Comment: I just happen to mixed up the data... I have already modified the data. The question is still valid

Comment: What you are doing will simply make insertions slower. If you want to speed up data insertion, use the batch insert/bulk import mechanism of your database. Adding a lot of records "concurrently" means you have a whole lot more connections conflicting, trying to access the same disk.

Comment: Google "Amdahl's law"

Comment: If you need to run 2000 threads, you should rethink how you are doing things... There are ways to bulk insert records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this just shows that your Inserts do not scale well. Your first scanario launches 2000 threads and waits for them to finish - the second scenario launches 4 threads and waits for them to finish, 500 times.

Using Threads adds an overhead to the execution that itself can slow down your code, if all threads end up into the same database that cannot handle that many connections your execution times get worse. Maybe you could test your Example without multiple threads, put the calls directly into the loop and look at the numbers, possibly this runs even faster.

Comment: Actually it's worse than that. The thread overhead is minimal compared to the IO overhead of communicating with the database. 2000 threads trying to insert records in a database is 2000 individual connections with their latencies, locks and conflicts. A bulk import of 2000 rows on the other hand is less than trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am just using these threads to do database insertion. Do you mean opening up too much database connection, burden the server and hence worsening the execution time?

Comment: In that case, if I implement second approaches into the working environment, there should not be any problem right?

Comment: Humongously. Transaction Monitor products were created in the 90s to *limit* the number of concurrent connections to the database, thus reducing conflicts. Use your database's bulk import command to load the data, or at least batch multiple statements in a single SQL statement to avoid the roundtrips.

Comment: @Ping NO DON'T. It's a VERY BAD approach! It's just that the first one is infinitely worse. NOTHING is going to be as fast as using bulk insert, eg using SQL Server's 'BULK INSERT' command or at least the SqlBulkCopy class from a client

Comment: Stephan, I agree that putting those calls into a loop and execute them like a queue will make the process faster. however, if the process is not just a simple database insert operation. Multithread will be useful.

Comment: @Ping if it isn't a simple DB operation, break it apart so that the DB operations can run separately

Comment: @Ping thats right, if you absolutely must use threads, find a plausible limit. Like the numbers of scenario 2 show, four threads looks good. VB.net has a threadpool that is configureable and has other benefits: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4732ks0.aspx

Comment: I think I got my answer. It all depends on scenario for how many consecutive thread I want to run. For each multithread application, testing has to be done one by one to get its maximized performance.